# XrmToolbox Connectivity issue with Dynamics 365 environment

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, xrmtoolbox

I am trying to create connection on my XrmToolbox using Connection Wizard.

I am trying to establish connection with the Dev environment. I pass the the instance url and credentials. But, upon finishing the setup, the connection is switching to our prod environment. The org ID is switching to that of the prod environment.

I tried to use the url using my dev environment org unique name and it is still switching to my prod environment.

Url I'm pasisng: https://org2c******.crm.dynamics.com

It is switching to: https://orgd1******.crm.dynamics.com

I am tried with the previous version of XrmToolbox and I am still having the issue.

Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with user type in the AAD. I was setup as a guest user. this is why system was not allowing me to access the Dev environment from the XRMToolBox or Plugin Reg tool. This was sorted when my user type was changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to confirm internal and display names. Also you can connect via SDK login Control, that will give you the ability to switch org.

Comment: Thank you. You were right about the SDK login Control. This is a correct step, but the issue was somewhere else though.